# Matching Landsat 8 with previous Landsat images

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, landsat

I am working with Landsat 8 in ENVI. My image's dimensions are 8921 x 13131. I need to apply a forest mask to this image with dimensions of 8805 x 12321. I try to resize an image, but it doesn't work. (After that I need to calculate forest disturbance index for 2013 and subtract it from DI for 2000, so I really need  an 2013 image (Landsat 8) to be resized).

I resize it using basic tool - spatial subset - subset using - file - and then pick my forest mask. However, as a result I get a file of 8806 x 12321 instead of 8805. If I adjust the number of samples manually, it gives me 8805. But then I try to apply a mask and that's what I get (see a screenshot).  They just don't match. And when I try to overlay my mask (which I made based on Landsat 7 image) with my Landsat 8 image, those two images have different frames.

Does anybody have any good advice?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The extents are not exactly the same but this is normal. you should not change the number of pixels by changing their size (what resize does) but by changing the extent using [subset](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Subsetting.html) by file (or by ROI if you want to have the minimum extent of the two images).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using subset by file, it gives me 8806 samples instead of 8805. And then ENVI doesn't allow to mask a 8806 file with 8805 mask :(

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by changing the mask to ROI and using the tool "reconcile ROIs" to match the mask and landsat 8 image.